# where can I get the detailed tutorial or document for Q# machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-computing, q#

Recently, I'm learning the Q# language for machine learning. The sample of half-moons has been run correctly. Now I want to learn the detail of the code. But there is too little explanation to find. There are too many methods I can't understand and there are no introductions in detail. For example, it only explains the name, parameters for the method, but no further information.[image]
I really can't understand it.
So is there an exits detailed document for machine learning for beginners? Thank u very much.

how to get the detained document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q# machine learning library implements one specific approach, circuit-centric quantum classifiers. You can find the documentation for this approach at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/libraries/machine-learning/intro and the subsequent pages in that section. The paper it's based on is  ['Circuit-centric quantum classifiers', Maria Schuld, Alex Bocharov, Krysta Svore and Nathan Wiebe](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00633).